# Cannot read properties of null reading querySelector in jasmine

Tags: angular, validation, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms, angular12

I´m trying to test a small reactive form in Angular 12, I have this:

The ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';
import { IFrequency } from '../data/ifrequency';
import { Colaborador } from '../data/colaborador';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { ServicioSettings } from '../data/servicio-settings';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-consultar-colaborador',
  templateUrl: './consultar-colaborador.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consultar-colaborador.component.css']
})
export class ConsultarColaboradorComponent implements OnInit {

  colaborador: Colaborador = {
    numeroDeIndentificacion: 33,
    nombres: null,
    apellidos: null,
    direccion: null,
    email: null,
    telefono: null,
    salario: null,
    fk_Area: null,
    fechaDeIngreso: null,
    sexo: null,
    codigoInterno: null
  };

  items: Colaborador;
  myForm: FormGroup;    
  submitted = false;  

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  iniciarFormulario(){
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({        
      numeroDeIndentificacion: new FormControl(this.colaborador.numeroDeIndentificacion, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)])      
    });
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.iniciarFormulario();  
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.myForm.invalid) {
      alert ('Error')
      return      
    }
    
    //console.log(this.myForm.value.numeroDeIndentificacion);
    this.dataService.ConsultarColaboradorPorIdentificacion(this.myForm.value.numeroDeIndentificacion).subscribe(
      //result => console.log('success ', result),
      result =>  this.items = result,
      error => console.log('error ', error)
    );     
  }
}
```

The html file:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="numeroDeIndentificacion">NumeroDeIndentificacion (*)</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numeroDeIndentificacion" name="numeroDeIndentificacion" formControlName="numeroDeIndentificacion" >
        <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').invalid && (myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').dirty || myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').touched)">    
             
            <div *ngIf="myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').errors.required">
                El numeroDeIndentificacion es requerido
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').errors.minlength">
                El numeroDeIndentificacion debe ser mínimo de 3 caracteres
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="myForm.get('numeroDeIndentificacion').errors.maxlength">
                El numeroDeIndentificacion debe ser máximo de 30 caracteres
              </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-send" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

The spect file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ConsultarColaboradorComponent } from './consultar-colaborador.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ConsultarColaboradorComponent', () => {
    let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let component: ConsultarColaboradorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConsultarColaboradorComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ConsultarColaboradorComponent ],
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
     // Inject the http service and test controller for each test
     httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
     httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConsultarColaboradorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should check numeroDeIdentificacion', () => {
      const numeroDeIdentificacionElement: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#myForm')
                                                    .querySelector('input')[0];
        numeroDeIdentificacionElement.value = "0";
        numeroDeIdentificacionElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        const isLogginFormValid = component.myForm.valid;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(()=> {
```

Here I tried:

const numeroDeIdentificacionValue = component.myForm.get('numeroDeIdentificacion');
expect(numeroDeIdentificacionElement.value).toBeGreaterThan(numeroDeIdentificacionValue.value);

And latter:

```
    expect(isLogginFormValid).toBeTruthy();


      })  
    // expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
```

If you know how to test a form, or if you can share a link the help would be very appreciated. Or of course, if you can suggest me a change.

If I put:

```
.querySelector('numeroDeIndentificacion');
```

I guet:

```
Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
```

Comment: Try to add the `id` to the `form` as follows: `<form id="myForm" ...`

Comment: I did it, now it shows:  TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value') @uminder

Comment: `querySelector()` returns the first `Element` but not an array. Omit `[0]` at `.querySelector('input')[0]` or use `querySelectorAll('input')[0]`.

Comment: With .querySelector('input');   removing the [0] it worked, thanks @uminder